# I need to know the callback when I edit a jqGrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am implementing jqGrid and need a call back when I edit row, for add and delete, gridComplete is getting fired but when I edit the row none of the events are fired. I have tried many as given in the documentation of jqGrid. Below is the code:

```
tableID.jqGrid({
    //  scroll:1,
        altRows:true,
    //  ajaxGridOptions:{async:false},
        data:clientSideData,
        datatype: "local",
        //mtype: reqType,
        colNames:columnName,
        colModel :columnModel,
        pager: '#pager_'+wargs.uuid,
        rowNum:rowNumber,
        rowList:listOfRow,
        sortname: sortByCol,
        sortorder: sortOrder,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: titleGrid,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems : false},
        gridview:true,
        //cellsubmit:'clientArray',
        //cellEdit: editable,
        onSelectRow: function(id){
            if(editable == "true"){
                if(id && id !== lastsel){
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                    lastsel=id;
                }
            }
        },
    //  loadonce: true,
        loadBeforeSend : function(xhr) {
            dataField.val(getRowDataAsJson());console.log(dataField.val());
        },
        gridComplete : function() {
            dataField.val(getRowDataAsJson());console.log(dataField.val());
        },
        loadError : function(xhr,status,error){
            dataField.val(getRowDataAsJson());console.log(dataField.val());
        },
        editurl: wargs.args.dummyURI
    });

tableID.jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager_"+wargs.uuid,
    {edit:editable,add:editable,del:editable},
    {closeAfterEdit: editable,closeOnEscape:editable,reloadAfterSubmit:editable});
```

Please don't bother about the values like editable and wargs.uuid, it was set not mentioned here as not required.

Comment: Which type has `editable` variable? Is if boolean or string variable with the value "true"? What do you mean under "i edit the row none"? Do you want to have a callback on cancel of row editing? Do you want to use local editing with dummy url as editurl? Is editing itself work and you want to have an callback after the end of data editing? How you see I have too many opened questions to be able to answer you.

Comment: editable is boolean, actually it is written like when i edit row, none of events are fired. no i dint want any event on cancel of row editing. yes i want local editing, dummy url is mandatory because without using, it throws and error like url is not set.i actually want an callback when i click on submit button, after editing a row..